# MCX redirection on OSX network users

Tags: macos

Hi I have an open directory network
users login with network based user home folder
I am trying to redirect the ~/Library/Caches folder to a /tmp/User/Library/Caches folder using MCX redirection using workgroup manager on the group
I have setup the redirect as per below
 [image]

I can see that it works as on login the /tmp/User/Library/Caches folder is created, however no applications are using it, they continue to create items in the ~/Library/Caches folder

Can anyone assist in telling me what I am missing to get the new cache folder to be used? I have other managed preferences setup e.g. hide wifi icon and they work perfectly. So I know they are being used.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question
The user did not have permission to delete original ~/Library/Caches folder therefore the MCX failed
Manually deleting the ~/Library/Caches folder on the server allowed MCX to generate the new symlink